# Set background of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have problem when I try set background of LinearLayout (layout_after)
when I try :

```
layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout_after);
Drawable temp = Drawable.CreateFromStream(AfterConnectionLayout.backgroundStream, "home_background");
layout.SetBackgroundDrawable(temp);
```

Image is load but not correct - my Toolbar is It becomes invisible.
Where I do fail ?

Secend problem is when I try set background of header nav menu ( i don't see result , background no change )

```
nav = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
View vie = nav.GetHeaderView(0);
vie.SetBackgroundColor(MenuLayout.header_color);
```

This is axml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_after">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/poprawnaczynnosc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Pomyślnie połączono z komputerem"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Możesz teraz skanować faktury."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/skanujfakture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:id="@+id/kanujfakture"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/stopkaView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header" />
```

Edit1 :I resolve problem with background :

```
drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
Drawable temp = Drawable.CreateFromStream(AfterConnectionLayout.backgroundStream, "home_background");
drawerLayout .SetBackgroundDrawable(temp);
```